# Unity Chartboost

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, chartboost

Can someone explain how to use Chartboost sdk in unity. I've already downloaded the sdk and have in my project but I need to know how to get started and how to program with the built in methods. Also I would like to know how to test out the ads if they work on my device

Answer (score 3):

Chartboost have a really detailed step by step guide that can be found here.

https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200780379-Unity-Integration

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use Prime31 Chartboost plugin,simple and quick, you can be found here:
https://prime31.com/docs#iosChartboost

Answer (score 0):

1. open unity
2. assets>import_package>select chartboost.unity
3. In unity Editor>click chartboost
4. create new scene>make settings of chartboost like android/ios
5. test it in real device
   6.https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200780379-Unity-Integration

Answer (score 0):

Adding the SDK to your games is quick and easy – you just need a few ingredients:

A Chartboost account
An app in your dashboard
The latest SDK
An active publishing campaign
Please note that Chartboost supports `Android 2.3+ and iOS 6.0`, so make sure to set the minimum OS versions of your Unity project accordingly.
Also, to ensure compatibility with `Android 6.0 Marshmallow` devices and features, you should make sure that you’re building, compiling, and targeting against the latest `Google Android SDKs (at least API level 23)`. (However, “minimum” SDK can still target down to API Level 9.)
The Chartboost initialization call must be made during hard and soft bootups within the first few seconds of your app launching, regardless of any other actions or user interaction within your app.